# Red5 1.0.0 application rejects connections

Tags: java, red5, rtmp

I have a RED5 application, which works under Red5 0.8.0 (although it drops the connection on RTMPT after couple seconds). I've checked out the latest revision (which is 4441) and made some changes to the app. Now I cannot connect to the application. I get everytime - NetConnection.Connect.Rejected.

In the logs I see:

```
[INFO] [http-0.0.0.0-80-exec-3] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-3] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 : 52966 to localhost (in: 3458 out: 3262), with id 1 due to long handshake
```

The handshake time is set to 15 seconds, so it must be enough. In the logs I am not even getting any attempts to try to connect. I have a log with the method name in start, connect, disconnect methods, however these won't be shown.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

*due to long handshake* can also mean you have still some browser window open that tries to connect to the application after you did re-start red5.
You always have to close all browser windows when you restart red5.

Also the first thing you need to look at is the red5/error.log. 
Nothing else counts :)
I guess you have some startup issue, Red5 0.8 are not 100% compatible to latest versions.

Sebastian

Comment: I restarted the server, closed every browser window and it didn't help. In the error log I just see the lines from the original post, i.e. Closing .... due to long handshake. What could be another reason for this?

Comment: Funny thing is I get this in logs: [INFO] [pool-8-thread-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect. However the overridden method appConnect won't get logged. Or at least I don't see that in logs.

Comment: there is a red5-debug.sh/bat. Use that instead and watch the console/log output. It prints more messages to the log. Really look at the startup log when you boot the server, not just navigate to the start page. That the page loads at all does not mean that the red5 srever did boot 100% correctly.

Comment: I am using that, it says nothing. Just the one message with the Action connect, than nothing, and afterwards come the Error messages with Due to a long handshake...

Comment: The startup log is way longer then those couple of lines. It contains for example version info about red5 and more.

Comment: Of course. I didn't mean, that those lines are the only one in the log. But otherwise, there is no error, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

A possible case of connection rejection from the server is user authentication failure.If you implement that in the connect method of your application check that the user gets authenticated. RTMP connection closure just tells you that the server pinged the client after every X ms and after certain number of such trials server got no response from the client(which is called as handshake timeout).In that case server closes the connection with the 'idle' client.